# Ist it possible to combine dimensions and metrics in calculated fields?

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

We have the variables:

- "Unique User"
- "Version" (Plus, Light in a ratio 79:21 from all Unique User)
- "total Events"
- "Eventkatagories".

And following scenario:
We can't get the exact data how many users are plus or light users.
But we know how many events are triggered by version (plus/light).

Now we want to know how the relative frequency of events triggered grouped by Version and event category. 
So in a pivot table there is the row dimension = Version and the column Dimension = event category.
So the measurement should be the relative frequency.

So the simple custom calculated field should be "total events / users"... But remember we can't get the absolute value of Users by Version, we just know the ratio (80-20).

So I build another calculated field called UsersbyVersion with following statement:

```
CASE
  WHEN (Version = "light") THEN SUM(User) * 0.21
  WHEN (Version = "Plus") THEN SUM(User) * 0.79
END
```

But this formula gives following error:

> Invalid formula - Invalid input expression. - Failed to parse CASE
>   statement

If I use absolute numbers for the statement it works. 
Example:

```
CASE
  WHEN (Version = "Normal") THEN 5000
  WHEN (Version = "Plus") THEN 25000
END
```

But we need the statement "User * ration" ... the ratio won't change a lot but the user value in relation to the date we want to set on the Data Studio Report.

So I guess the problem is that the statement won't work with a combination of metrics and dimensions.
I already tried putting the "User * 0.79" and "User * 0.21" in custom metrics but this won't work aswell.

Is there a way to combine dimensions and metrics in a calculated field as an measurement?

Thx for your help

Answer (score -1):

Create 2 metrics -

1. users * 0.2 (lets call this UsersP2)
2. users * 0.8 (lets call this UsersP8)

[image: UserP2]

Now this should work

```
CASE
  WHEN (Version = "light") THEN UserP2
  WHEN (Version = "Plus") THEN UserP8
END
```

[image: Calculated field]

Dataset

[image: Example dataset]
Result

[image: Result]

Comment: This throws the error that you can't use mathematical operations in a if/else statement. So this doesn't work either.

Comment: You're right. I've editted and that should now work.

Comment: Sadly not, already tried that:

"So I guess the problem is that the statement won't work with a combination of metrics and dimensions. I already tried putting the "User * 0.8" and "User * 0.2" in custom metrics but this won't work aswell."

Error: "You can't combine metrics (summarized) with dimensions (non-summarized)  in a calculated field."

Comment: The user metrics shouldn't be summarised. Make sure they aren't summarised in your data source or in the metrics you created

Comment: Formula in calc. field 1 is like you commented and the fields "UserP2" are just calculated fields with: "User*0.8" or "User*0.2",  No summarised fields.
It don't work like this

Comment: I've added some pictures there. Worth seeing if anything differs from the dataset setup or calculations